# Is it possible using Struts 2 file upload to not create temp file?

Tags: java, struts2, apache-commons-fileupload

I have a requirement to keep the file in memory until it hits the action class and never write the file to disk. There is a fear of some exploit that could take place on the server the file is uploaded to if it resides even just a few seconds on disk.  I feel the Struts2 framework is setup to for one solution only that that is to store the file temporarily to disk. Is this a correct assumption, or am I missing something really simple?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incase it is of some interest, and so I can close out this question, I wanted to share how I accomplished the requirement of not saving the uploaded file temporarily to disk.

First, I had the business agree to a reasonable max size for the file to be uploaded, and to allow only one file at a time to be uploaded.  By not having this agreement, my solution outlined below would not work.

There is a plugin feature of struts that I made use of.  I created my own MutiPartRequest plugin and class based off of the JarkartaMultiPartRequest class. I commented out all writes to the file system.  Set a max file size of 10MB.  Set the sizeThreshold in the parser to be a bit greater than 10MB.  By setting the sizeThreshold to be larger then the maxSize, it created one item in memory that held the entire byte array of the uploaded file.  I then created a custom attribute in the http request to hold my in memory byte array so I could access it in the action class.  There was no other way I could find to get at the byte array.

There were a few other clean up items I had to do, but overall the approach seemed to work well.

Answer (score 0):

One way I can think of would be to set `struts.multipart.saveDir` to a directory on your filesystem (such as a subdirectory of `/tmp`) and have that directory mounted as a memory-backed storage. That will ensure that nothing will reside on disk.

A small, tiny caveat however: even though the filesystem is memory-backed, portions of it may be written to disk by some low-level OS mechanism (paging, for instance). However, that is true for anything you store in memory, not just memory-backed filesystems. If this storage must absolutely remain in memory and never even paged, you'll need to get a bit more creative and ensure that the memory backed by the filesystem is always "resident".

Comment: Very creative way to meet the requirement of not storing on disk.  The problem is if it looks like a file and can be accessed like a file then this will not pass.